# Is there a way to make a field draggable and editable in Angular?

Tags: angular, draggable, contenteditable

I've been experimenting with Angular 8's DragDropModule in the CDK. While I am able to make a field or text draggable, there doesn't seem to be a way to make it draggable and editable. It appears the dragging cancels out the editing of a field.

You can edit:

```
<h2 contenteditable="true"> --- Edit Me! :) --- </h2>
```

You can drag:

```
<h2 cdkDrag> --- Drag Me! :) --- </h2>
```

But not both:

```
<h2 cdkDrag contenteditable="true"> --- What a drag! :( --- </h2>
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61128879/5214911) for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep things simple and only use what `cdkDragDrop` provides, you could use the `cdkDragHandle` property. Using this the dragging will only work using the specified handle and you will be able to edit the content you want inside the element.

I know it doesn't fully solve your issue, but if you don't need to drag from anywhere on the element, it's an option.

[Small example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5uv7x9)

Comment: Thanks. This is where all JavaScript Frameworks fall flat on their faces. Eventually, you'll encounter a scenario where you have to face the evil of JavaScript in order to customize a feature.